# always have check next to the text in checkbox control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, checkbox, alignment

I have an odd, seemly easy question.  I have around 6 checkbox controls on my form which need to be right aligned for best cosmetic look and appeal.  My question is, is there a way, through code or properties, to always have the checkbox on a checkbox control to as close to the left of the text no matter what length of the text?

Currently there's options to align the check and the text but with the text being constantly changing from long length to short, it would be great if the checkbox could stick next to the text at all times.  Is this possible?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: I'm not sure I can visualize this.  You want the text to be right-aligned, with the checkbox on the left side, immediately before the text?  So the right edges of the text line up, and the checkboxes don't?  If so, try my answer out.  If not, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Set `AutoSize` to `True` (default)
- Set `RightToLeft` to `No` (default)
- Set `Anchor` to `Right` only (non-default)

Comment: Oh wow.  I feel stupid.  I thought of this, but I figured that wouldn't honor that when you changed the text.  Nice.  +1

Comment: @StevenDoggart - Yeah, setting the anchor is kindof non-intuitive.  I had to experiment with it to realize that it actually worked.

Comment: I did not believe - tried it and it works like a charm! This would probably be another one of those solutions which will get the person 1000+ upvotes. :)

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks for taking the time to help find this solution!